# How do I insert dictionary values into a parameter

Tags: python, function, loops, dictionary

I am a beginner in python and have a question.

I created a dictionary with values in three.
I want to insert these values into the parameter( `pii:` see the entire code) of the function so that they change every 5 time steps(entire time step 50).

If you have any ideas, please let me know.
Thank you

```
- time step 1~5 C value is "5"      key "0"  (1st value)
# - time step 6~10 C  value is "10"   key "1"(2nd value)
# - time step 11~15 C  value is "15"   key "2"(3rd value )
# - time step 16~20  value C is "5" key "0"( 1st value)
# - time step 21~25  value C is "10"  key "1" (2nd value )....
```

Entire code

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate

def degrees_to_radians(theta_d,pii):

"""
Convert an angle from degrees to radians.
Parameters
----------

theta_d : float
    The angle in degrees.

Returns
-------

theta_r : float
    The angle in radians.
"""
theta_r = pii / 180.0 * theta_d
return theta_r


# I want to insert the values from this dictionary into pii.
# When inserting, each value must change every 5 timesteps.
# 
# Example
#  
# - time step 1~5 C value is "5"      key "0"  (1st value)
# - time step 6~10 C  value is "10"   key "1"(2nd value)
# - time step 11~15 C  value is "15"   key "2"(3rd value )
# - time step 16~20  value C is "60" key "0"( 1st value)
# - time step 21~25  value C is "5"  key "1" (2nd value )....

#dictionary TUA
# TUA={"0":5,
# "1":10,
# "2":15,
#}

for n in range(1,50):
    #pii=3.14
    print(degrees_to_radians(15*n,pii))
```

Comment: Please make a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Could you tell me in more detail what it means to be minimal reproducible?? I thought I made it as simple as possible, but If there is something you don't understand, please tell me about the problem in more detail.Thank you.

Comment: Math is scary and specific. Get rid of the Euler method and focus on your programming problem! `AEA` looks very complicated, can you simplify it so it only needs 2 parameters? Can you simplify the calculations, maybe just add the parameters up? Your code example doesn't need to make sense/have a real world use case, we only need to see what you are trying to do in Python. (same for the for loop, you don't need 864 iterations to illustrate your problem)

Comment: Is that better ???

Comment: This is much better! You could still uncomment `TUA` and fix the indentation for `degrees_to_radians`. But I think I already know what you mean. One more thing: Do you use Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I'm using Phyton 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to iterate `n` times, but use the same key for `k` (=5) consecutive loops.

So you need a way to map

| x | key |
| --- | --- |
| 1.. 5 | 0 |
| 6..10 | 1 |
| 11..15 | 2 |
| 16..20 | 3 |

an so on

The magic word here is `integer division`:

`f(x) = x // 5` will map

| x | f(x) |
| --- | --- |
| 0..4 | 0 |
| 5..9 | 1 |
| 10..14 | 2 |
| 15..19 | 3 |

and so on.
That is not quite what you want, but `f(x) = (x-1) // 5` is!

So you can write

```
for i in range(1,50):
    index = (i - 1) // 5
    pii = TUA[str(index)]
    degrees_to_radians(pii)
```

But there is one more catch: you don't want to map 16..20 to 3, you want to start at 0 again. What can be done? `Modulo`! `g(x) = x % 3` will map 0,3,6,9,.. all to 0.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I solved the problem by setting ' index = ((i-1) // 5)%3 '  like this. You saved my life. God bless you !!